# Customer community builder, edit CSS of single page

Tags: lightning-experience, css, community-builder

I want to edit css of a SINGLE page of a community experience.
I want to apply these two rules:

```
cursor:not-allowed;
pointer-events:none;
```

Only for this page:

[image]

If i apply these rules on community css editor, they are applied on ALL pages:
[image]

I tried this but it doesn't work:

.Transaction-Journal-List .forceCommunityObjectHome .forceActionRow.uiInfiniteListRow .body

Can anyone tell me how to edit the css ONLY of a page?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is posted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314176/apply-css-code-to-one-page-variation-only-in-community)

Each page has its own class within the body tag. Look for it and add it to the selector.
[image]

Given the name of your page, the selector should look like this, I believe:

```
.comm-page-custom-transaction-journal-list .forceCommunityObjectHome .forceActionRow.uiInfiniteListRow .body {
    cursor:not-allowed;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```